# Работа c htaccess. как убрать расширение файла

Tags: .htaccess, php

Вообщем то вопрос вот такой.

Как с помощью Htaccess убрать расширение файла

пытался вот так

```
RewriteEngine ON
```

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

Но таким методом не фиксируется файл index.php

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Не помогает

Вообщем вопрос как убрать расширение при этом чтобы сервер видел индексные файлы
например Index.php, login.php

Comment: я тут случайно обнаружил вот такую http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php там можно поиграть с настройками и чтобы расширение скрыть и тд..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перенаправляйте все запросы на PHP, а далее делайте что хотите, вот вам кастрированный вариант MVC, очень просто с него начать и далее всё пойдёт как по маслу. Зачем это надо? Даст вам такие урлы как:

```
http://yoursite.com/
http://yoursite.com/products/
http://yoursite.com/mobile/apple/iphone-5c-cyan/
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* router.php [L]
```

router.php

```
<?php

$exe_deep = 0; // Глубина в подпапках (0 - если лежит в корне)

$route = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); 
$route = array_filter($route);
array_splice($route, 0, $exe_deep);

if (empty($route[0])) { $route[0] = 'index'; }

$exe_mod_file = $route[0] . '.php';

// Run module!
if (file_exists($exe_mod_file)) { Include_once($exe_mod_file); }
else { header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found'); Include_once ('404.php'); }

?>
```